# Converting this MySQL query to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

This is the query that i would like to be converted into MSSQL. I really tried so hard on searching online to convert everything line by line. I really do hope someone can help me :(

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `EmployeesLOG`(IN `vIDNumber` varchar(20), IN `vMonth` varchar(20), IN `EmployeesGroup` varchar(50))
BEGIN
SELECT logtime.IDNumber, concat(Last_Name,', ' ,First_Name,' ',left(Middle_Name,1),'.') AS Employee, profile.Employees_Group,
IFNULL( group_concat( case when logtime.InOutMode In ('IN-AM') then STR_TO_DATE(EmployeesLog.LogTime,'%T') end Order By case when EmployeesLog.InOutMode In ('IN-AM') then STR_TO_DATE(EmployeesLog.LogTime,'%T') end ASC SEPARATOR ',  ' ),'') AS IN_AM,
IFNULL( group_concat( case when EmployeesLog.InOutMode In ('OUT-AM') then STR_TO_DATE(EmployeesLog.LogTime,'%T') end Order By case when EmployeesLog.InOutMode In ('OUT-AM') then STR_TO_DATE(EmployeesLog.LogTime,'%T') end DESC SEPARATOR ',  ' ),'') AS OUT_AM,
STR_TO_DATE(EmployeesLog.LogDate,'%m/%d/%Y') AS iDate FROM EmployeesLog Inner Join profile ON EmployeesLog.IDNumber = profile.IDNumber where   DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(EmployeesLog.LogDate,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%M%Y')=vMonth and EmployeesLog.IDNumber like vIDNumber
and TRIM( Profile.Employees_Group) like (CONCAT('%', TRIM(EmployeesGroup))) GROUP BY IDNumber, iDate Order by  Employee ASC, iDate ASC;
END
```

Thank you in advance

```
EmployeeID  Employee             Employees_Group  IN_AM      OUT_AM     iDate
1001        Agustin, Mirasol D.  COA OFFICE       04:46:47,  11:02:01,        10/01/2020
                                                  04:46:54,  11:02:43
                                                  04:47:05   
1001        Agustin, Mirasol D.  COA OFFICE       05:01:04   12:11:01, 10/02/2020
                                                             12:11:41
1001        Agustin, Mirasol D.  COA OFFICE       04:58:12   12:03:23  10/03/2020
                                                  04:58:44
```

Comment: Please have a go, making use of the official docs, and google, and only post a question when stuck on a specific problem.

Comment: I really did sir @DaleK but i am currently low on experience since i am currently a 3rd year college student :( i'm just hoping someone could help me and make it my experience for constructing a MSSQL query

Comment: There are loads and loads of resources out there to assist with this. These days the main skill of a developer is googling resources on how to do stuff. You'll learn it much better than if someone just does it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the motivation @DaleK. I'm just having a hard time learning MSSQL stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Conversion

If you decide to go for the most literal conversion, then you will find some pointers below:

- [Create stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure) syntax
- `concat` => [concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql)
- `group_concat` => [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql)
- `ifnull` => [isnull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql), [nullif](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql), [coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)
- `trim` => [trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql)
- `date_format`, `str_to_date` => [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

---

### Rebuild

An alternative would be to build a new solution from the ground up. That is what I have done below.

**Sample data**

```
create table EmployeeProfile
(
    IDNumber int,
    FirstName nvarchar(20),
    MiddleName nvarchar(20),
    LastName nvarchar(20),
    EmplGroup nvarchar(10)
);
insert into EmployeeProfile (IDNumber, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, EmplGroup) values
(1001, 'Mirasol', 'Dirk', 'Agustin', 'COA OFFICE');

create table EmployeeLog
(
    IDNumber int,
    InOutMode nvarchar(6),
    LogDate date,
    LogTime time
);
insert into EmployeeLog (IDNumber, InOutMode, LogDate, LogTime) values
(1001, 'IN-AM',  '2020-10-01', '04:46:47'),
(1001, 'OUT-AM', '2020-10-01', '11:02:01'),
(1001, 'IN-AM',  '2020-10-01', '04:46:54'),
(1001, 'OUT-AM', '2020-10-01', '11:02:43'),
(1001, 'IN-AM',  '2020-10-01', '04:47:05'),
(1001, 'IN-AM',  '2020-10-02', '05:01:04'),
(1001, 'OUT-AM', '2020-10-02', '12:11:01'),
(1001, 'OUT-AM', '2020-10-02', '12:11:41'),
(1001, 'IN-AM',  '2020-10-03', '04:58:12'),
(1001, 'OUT-AM', '2020-10-03', '12:03:23'),
(1001, 'IN-AM',  '2020-10-03', '04:58:44');
```

**Selection**

You can spot some elements from my pointers above making an appearance. Additionally the solution contains [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql), [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) and [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot).

```
with cte as
(
    select  el.IDNumber as 'EmployeeID',
            ep.LastName + ', ' + ep.FirstName + ' ' + left(ep.MiddleName, 1) + '.' as 'Employee',
            ep.EmplGroup,
            el.InOutMode,
            el.LogDate,
            el.LogTime,
            row_number() over(partition by el.LogDate, el.InOutMode order by el.LogTime) as 'RowNum'
    from EmployeeLog el
    join EmployeeProfile ep
        on ep.IDNumber = el.IDNumber
)
select  case when p.RowNum = 1 then convert(nvarchar, p.EmployeeID) else '' end as 'EmployeeID',
        case when p.RowNum = 1 then p.Employee else '' end as 'Employee',
        case when p.RowNum = 1 then p.EmplGroup else '' end as 'Employees_Group',
        isnull(convert(nvarchar, p.[IN-AM], 108), '') as 'IN_AM',
        isnull(convert(nvarchar, p.[OUT-AM], 108), '') as 'OUT_AM',
        case when p.RowNum = 1 then convert(nvarchar, p.LogDate, 101) else '' end as 'iDate'
from cte c
pivot (max(c.LogTime) for c.InOutMode in ([IN-AM], [OUT-AM])) p;
```

**Result**

```
EmployeeID Employee            Employees_Group IN_AM    OUT_AM   iDate
---------- ------------------- --------------- -------- -------- ----------
1001       Agustin, Mirasol D. COA OFFICE      04:46:47 11:02:01 10/01/2020
                                               04:46:54 11:02:43 
                                               04:47:05          
1001       Agustin, Mirasol D. COA OFFICE      05:01:04 12:11:01 10/02/2020
                                                        12:11:41 
1001       Agustin, Mirasol D. COA OFFICE      04:58:12 12:03:23 10/03/2020
                                               04:58:44
```

---

**Stored procedure**

Some notes:

- The date parameters (year and month) are passed as separate integers to avoid string conversions and matching a string pattern.
- The `trim()` from around the field `EmplGroup` was removed, clean up the data in the database or add the `trim()` back.

Create procedure:

```
create procedure proc_EmployeeReport
    @vIDNumber int,
    @vMonth int,
    @vYear int,
    @EmployeesGroup nvarchar(50)
as
with cte as
(
    select  el.IDNumber as 'EmployeeID',
            ep.LastName + ', ' + ep.FirstName + ' ' + left(ep.MiddleName, 1) + '.' as 'Employee',
            ep.EmplGroup,
            el.InOutMode,
            el.LogDate,
            el.LogTime,
            row_number() over(partition by el.LogDate, el.InOutMode order by el.LogTime) as 'RowNum'
    from EmployeeLog el
    join EmployeeProfile ep
        on ep.IDNumber = el.IDNumber
    where el.IDNumber = @vIDNumber
      and month(el.LogDate) = @vMonth
      and year(el.LogDate) = @vYear
      and ep.EmplGroup like concat('%',trim(@EmployeesGroup),'%')
)
select  case when p.RowNum = 1 then convert(nvarchar, p.EmployeeID) else '' end as 'EmployeeID',
        case when p.RowNum = 1 then p.Employee else '' end as 'Employee',
        case when p.RowNum = 1 then p.EmplGroup else '' end as 'Employees_Group',
        isnull(convert(nvarchar, p.[IN-AM], 108), '') as 'IN_AM',
        isnull(convert(nvarchar, p.[OUT-AM], 108), '') as 'OUT_AM',
        case when p.RowNum = 1 then convert(nvarchar, p.LogDate, 101) else '' end as 'iDate'
from cte c
pivot (max(c.LogTime) for c.InOutMode in ([IN-AM], [OUT-AM])) p;
```

Call procedure (results are the same as from selection):

```
exec proc_EmployeeReport @vIDNumber=1001, @vMonth=10, @vYear=2020, @EmployeesGroup='COA';
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir!!! You are a savior. This will make my stepping stone on learning MSSQL. I really do appreciate it sir. Thank you again sir and more power!! ^^